# pandas area plot interpolation / step style

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Is there a way to disable the interpolation in the pandas area plot?
I would like to get a "step-style" area plot.
E.g. in the normal line plot it is possible to specify:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':range(10)})
df.plot(drawstyle = 'steps') # this works
#df.plot(kind = 'area', drawstyle = 'steps') # this does not work
```

I am using python 2.7 and pandas 0.14.1.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, I worked out the workaround I originally suggested. I don't think you're going to get anything better built-in.

Answer (score 5):

Recently an [update](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/4433) of `.fill_between()` was shipped with **matplotlib version 1.5.0** that allows to fill the area between two step functions. This even works with Pandas time series.

Since the argument `step='pre'` exists, it can be used like this:

```
# For error bands around a series df
ax.fill_between(df.index, df - offset, df + offset, step='pre', **kwargs)

# For filling the whole area below a function
ax.fill_between(df.index, df, 0, step='pre', **kwargs)
```

Additional key word arguments that make sense to me are for example `alpha=0.3` and `lw=0`.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, `df.plot(drawstyle="steps")` doesn't even store the calculated step vertices;

```
out = df.plot(kind = 'line', drawstyle = 'steps') # stepped, not filled
stepline = out.get_lines()[0]
print(stepline.get_data())
```

> (array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
>   8, 9]))

so I think you'll have to roll your own. Which is just inserting `(x[i+1],y[i])` directly after every `(x[i],y[i])` in the list of points:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':range(10)})
x = df.x.values
xx = np.array([x,x])
xx.flatten('F')
doubled = xx.flatten('F') # NOTE! if x, y weren't the same, need a yy
plt.fill_between(doubled[:-1], doubled[1:], label='area')
ax = plt.gca()
df.plot(drawstyle = 'steps', color='red', ax=ax)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know if Pandas can plot it, but matplotlib can do it with a Pandas time series dataframe. New question?

Answer (score 1):

with area this isnot possbile but you can use a stacked bar plot do get what you want

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':range(10)})
df.plot(kind="bar",stacked=True,width = 1)
```

[image]